# I want to break the habit of "here's the thing"

Tags: synonyms, discourse-markers

What are some alternatives to this overused phrase?

Examples of use:

Person A: What's going on? Why did Person B do that?
Person C: Ummm... can we go somewhere more private?
A & C go to the corner
Person C: Here's the thing, Person B and Person D have a lot of personal history...

Person A: Why can't we just hire someone to do that one task? It's such a waste of time having five people rotating on that task every week.
Person B: Yeah, I hear ya.  Those five workers have brought that up too. But here's the thing: management believes it's fine the way it is and it's not worth hiring a person solely for that task.

Comment: Better "Here's the thing..." than "The thing about it is, is that..."

Comment: Here's the thing: if you use an alternative, you are not breaking the habit. You're just dressing it up in a different skirt. If you want to break the habit, then you will have to actually break the habit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are plenty of alternatives, e.g.

> So, you see, ...
>
> It appears to be the case that...
>
> Someone once told me that ...
>
> Strangely enough, ...
>
> You might be surprised to know that ...
>
> This may be hard to believe, but ...
>
> Guess what -- ...

I wouldn't go quite as far as KiloVoltaire in saying one should desist from such verbal mannerisms -- as he or she points out, they do have the function of enabling you to focus the attention of others on the substantive part of what you are about to say. And if they give the speaker time to marshal their thoughts or preserve an inner calm, then they serve a useful function in that way too.

My suggestions for anyone who suspects they might be overdoing these little verbal tics are, firstly, to try to monitor how often they use them, and secondly, to expand their repertoire so that their speech patterns are less repetitive and predictable. But keeping some redundancy in one's speech is not a bad thing -- the efficiency of the transfer of information is not necessarily the only goal of one's communication.

It is the little digressions, asides and familiar formulas that carry a lot of the emotional content of what we say -- not in terms of *what* we are saying, but *how* we are saying it.

The need to include such elements in order to establish the sense of connectedness between one person and another should not be underestimated. Part of the art of achieving really effective interpersonal communication is to find the right balance between these elements and the informational content.

Answer (score 3):

"Here's the thing..." and similar phrases (e.g., "The fact of the matter is...") are used as a crutch to allow others time to focus their attention on you. While it may be useful during a heated debate (i.e., while people are talking over each other), it almost never adds any real value to what is said immediately afterwards.

Exceptions to this would be when you are stating that you've reached a conclusion, or when you declare that you've discovered something. But exceptions aside, you would probably benefit from not saying it at all.

And how does one go about stopping it? By thinking before you speak ... which is something most people should do more often.

Comment: +1. You don't need any "look at me" introduction. Just say what you have to say -- the **message** itself, and forget about drawing attention to yourself or trying to get comfortable first. This is just a nervous tic, like clearing your throat each time before speaking.